# ajaxcontorltoolkit modal popup showing behind div position fixed

Tags: asp.net, css, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I have a header div on top of the page with `Position: fixed` in the master page.

In the content page, I have a modal Popup, that I would like to consume most of the screen, but the popup shows from the point where the header div ends (i.e., from the top)

I have this css for the popup and popup background classes...

```
.modalBackground {
    background-color: #AAAAAA;
    -moz-opacity: 0.7;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
}

.modalPopup {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px #e5e5e5;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #f5f6f5;
}
```

and this css is generated (after the modal popup is shown) for modal background:

```
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 10000;
    width: 1003px;
    height: 598px;
}
```

**UPDATE 1**
Here is the ModalPopup markup:

```
    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeImageViewer" runat="server" Drag="false" PopupControlID="pnlImageViewer" Y="90"
        TargetControlID="imgEmpty" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="imgClose" DropShadow="true">
    </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

and the Panel markup:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlImageViewer" runat="server" Style="display: none;" Width="975px" Height="550px" CssClass="modalPopup"></asp:Panel>
```

**UPDATE 2**
There is a menu in the Header, which also needs to be displayed. I am thankful to all the efforts made by people specially by *_*_.

I am going to share a screenshot of the popup in a few minutes

**UPDATE 3**

Attaching source code after Viewing source code from Chrome...
[Source Code](http://sdrv.ms/GMVE9r)

**UPDATE 4**

Attaching the corresponding CSS files...

[Menu.css](http://sdrv.ms/1hB9KGT)

[Default.css](http://sdrv.ms/1hB9Q1m)

Comment: Well i have readout your whole question i don't get you you want whole page background with popup ?

Comment: Can you add the related client HTML that is generated?

Comment: I have posted a potential solution; however, if this does not work for you, being able to see the client HTML will help a lot.

Comment: Awesome. Is there a way to post the CSS code too? I would like to see what all of their stacking contexts are if possible.

Comment: There are a lot of CSSs and the CSSs are themselves a mess, but let me send you what you want to see :) You will have to figure out yourself, what exactly is happening there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future questions, I highly recommend posting the generated HTML client code as well since that is what the CSS is acting upon. It will help people understand the problem faster and find a solution faster.

Without seeing your full source or client HTML, this is all speculation; however, I believe your issue is related to [the stack(ing) order](http://www.google.com/search?q=stacking%20order%20css).

Basically, what I imagine your setup to be (especially judging by your response to Rens Tillmann's answer) is the following:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">
    ...Fixed content showing above modal popup...
</div>
<div id="content">
    ...Modal background element + Modal popup content...
</div>
```

In this case, if `#header` has a `z-index` greater than that of `#content`'s `z-index` (assuming `#content` has proper stacking context), then the fixed header will always show up above the modal content because the modal content is in a subcontext of `#content`'s stacking context. This means that no matter what `z-index` you give the modal content, it will always be below `#header`.

[Here is a JSFiddle to illustrate the issue.](http://jsfiddle.net/SombreErmine/s2Px6/)

---

So, what can we do? There are *four solutions* to get the modal content above `#header` that I can think of at the moment.

**Solution 4 is the easiest potential solution if your website design allows it.**

---

## <s>Solution 1:</s>

Make `#content` have a higher stacking order than `#header`. This is not the answer, because I am assuming we need `#header` to float above `#content`.

Doing it this way will have the normal content show up above the header content.

[JSFiddle to illustrate why this won't work.](http://jsfiddle.net/SombreErmine/s2Px6/2/)

---

## Solution 2:

Put `#header` into the same stacking context as the modal. This can work; however, depending upon how your webpage is laid out in HTML and CSS, this may not be possible.

To put `#header` into the same stacking context as the modal, the easiest way would be to move it to be a `sibling` element of the modal.

[JSFiddle to illustrate this solution.](http://jsfiddle.net/SombreErmine/s2Px6/3/)

Another potential drawback of this solution is that it may be semantically confusing to have your header inside your content.

---

## Solution 3:

Put the modal background + content into the same stacking context of the `#header` element. Depending upon how your ASP.Net code is set up, this may not be possible. I don't fully grasp how AjaxControlToolkit works; so I don't know if this is possible or not.

The easiest way to do this would be to move the `ModalPopup` and `Panel` markups to be `siblings` of the `#header` element.

**HTML:**

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeImageViewer" runat="server" Drag="false" PopupControlID="pnlImageViewer" Y="90"
    TargetControlID="imgEmpty" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="imgClose" DropShadow="true">
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlImageViewer" runat="server" Style="display: none;" Width="975px" Height="550px" CssClass="modalPopup"></asp:Panel>
<div id="header">
    ...fixed header content...
</div>
<div id="content">
    ...regular content...
</div>
```

If you do this, their `z-index` values will be in the same context and can affect each other.

[Here is a JSFiddle to illustrate this in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/SombreErmine/s2Px6/4/)

---

**Note 1:**

In **Solution 3**, you can also put the modal in a stacking context higher than `#header`'s stacking context and it will still work.

For example, this would also work (assuming the modal has a higher `z-index` than the `#wrapper` element):

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeImageViewer" runat="server" Drag="false" PopupControlID="pnlImageViewer" Y="90"
    TargetControlID="imgEmpty" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="imgClose" DropShadow="true">
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlImageViewer" runat="server" Style="display: none;" Width="975px" Height="550px" CssClass="modalPopup"></asp:Panel>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        ...fixed header content...
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        ...regular content...
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**Note 2:**

To be in the same stacking context, you do not have to be sibling **elements**. You should have sibling **stacking contexts** though.

For example:

```
<div class="has-stacking-context" style="z-index: 2;">
    (stacking context sibling 1)
    ...content will show in middle...
</div>
<div class="no-stacking-context">
    <div class="no-stacking-context">
        <div class="has-stacking-context" style="z-index: 3;">
            (stacking context sibling 2)
            ...content will show above everything...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="has-stacking-context" style="z-index: 1;">
    (stacking context sibling 3)
    <div class="no-stacking-context">
        <div class="has-stacking-context" style="z-index: 100000;">
            (subcontext of sibling 3's stacking context)
            ...content will show below everything...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Moving elements physically (as I've done in Solution 2 and 3) just side-steps any need to remove various stacking contexts to get two stacking contexts to be siblings. Sometimes it is not possible to remove the stacking context of some elements.

---

## Solution 4 (can it be this simple?):

This is basically another way of doing Solution 3. Instead of physically moving the modal elements to match up the stacking contexts, we eliminate stacking contexts blocking the `#header` and modal element stacking contexts from being siblings.

Depending upon how your CSS is set up, this may or may not work.

For example, it may be possible to just remove the `#content` element's stacking context so that they become stacking context siblings.

[Here is a JSFiddle to illustrate the easiest potential solution.](http://jsfiddle.net/SombreErmine/s2Px6/6/)

Notice that I removed the `z-index` property (and `position` property) of the `#content` element. It now has no stacking context. You can do this to all ancestor elements of the modal elements to see if it works. Keep in mind though that some of those ancestors may actually need their stacking contexts...

---

## Final Solution (after chatting with you):

So, after looking at your code. I basically solved the issue using Solution 4. Your structure looks like the following:

```
<div class="HeaderContainer">
</div>
<div id="contentAreaMasterPage">
    <div id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_ImageThumbnailList_ImageViewer_mpeImageViewer_foregroundElement" style="position: fixed; z-index: 100001; left: 38.5px; top: 10px;">...</div>
    <div id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_ImageThumbnailList_ImageViewer_mpeImageViewer_backgroundElement" class="modalBackground" style="position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 10000; width: 1003px; height: 601px;"></div>
</div>
```

Because `.HeaderContainer` has a `z-index` of `10` and `#contentAreaMasterPage` has a `z-index` of `9`, everything inside `#contentAreaMasterPage` will always show up below `.HeaderContainer1`. So even though the two modal elements have `z-index` values more than 100 times that of `.HeaderContainer`'s `z-index` of `10`, they will always show up below it because they're inside `#contentAreaMasterPage`'s `z-index` of `9`.

Thus we want to get rid of `#contentAreaMasterPage`'s `z-index` so that it no longer has a stacking context to get in-between `.HeaderContainer`'s and the modal elements' `z-index` values. It's safe to remove the `z-index` in this case because `.HeaderContainer` will show up above `#contentAreaMasterPage` anyway without `#contentAreaMasterPage` needing a lower `z-index`.

**The related solution CSS code is thus simply:**

```
#contentAreaMasterPage {
    z-index: auto !important;
}
```

Which goes inside your specific page since you cannot modify the master template nor the master CSS file.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I think Solution 3 can fix the problem, but that is a very expensive problem considering that I have around 250 content pages in my project and only one master page and if I put the popup in the master page. It would not be feasible to hide it for all the remaining pages... I will look into it in detail though...

Comment: You're very welcome. In that case, I would see if Solution 4 would work for you since that would only touch CSS code (not ASP.Net or HTML code). I look forward to your update with more code. I will see if I can help further once I see it.

Comment: I also tried to change whole of the header for this particular page as a last ditch attempt, but the result was obviously that the header was not fixed and the header's menus and links were completely inaccessible now. Should I share my Page source ?

Comment: If you could share your page source and the CSS related to the page, that would help a lot!

Comment: **This was my previous comment, deleted it and then re-entered it here** I am sorry, about my earlier comment, I had tried that already. It did not work. :( That is what I did. #contentAreaMasterPage { position: relative !important; top: auto !important; }. I did that because I can not change the CSS for the entire site. I had to change the CSS for that particular page only

Comment: You should still be able to fix it on a page-by-page CSS basis if that is what you're limited to.

Comment: **Try changing:**
`.HeaderContainer { position: relative !important; z-index: auto !important; }
#contentAreaMasterPage { position: relative !important; top: auto !important; }`

**to:**
`/* .HeaderContainer { position: relative !important; z-index: auto !important; } */
#contentAreaMasterPage { position: relative !important; top: auto !important; z-index: auto !important; padding-top: 100px !important; }` (Edit: Just changed `static` back to `relative`)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38841/discussion-between-naveed-butt-and-sombreermine)

Answer (score 2):

When you have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="header">
   here is your header content
</div>
<div class="content">
   here is your model somewhere
</div>
```

And your **.header** has an `z-index:2;` and your **.content** has an `z-index:1;` the content inside this division (and maybe in this case your model) will always appear below your header.
I cannot think of anything else in this case.

Comment: You seem to be the only one understanding my question, but with no solution... :(

Comment: I am sure that it should be something like this. Can you paste your code in your question? It might help.

Comment: I have updated my question and will supply the screenshot and more code in a little time...

Answer (score 0):

try with `position: relative;` instead of `position: fixed;`

```
.modalPopup {
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px #e5e5e5;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #f5f6f5;
}


{
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 10000;
    width: 1003px;
    height: 598px;
}
```

for example

```
<tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSurveyId" runat="server" Style="display: none;" />
                            <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeSurveyId" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnSurveyId"
                                CancelControlID="imgCloseSurveyId" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" PopupControlID="pnlSurveyId"
                                PopupDragHandleControlID="pnlIdSurveyName" Drag="true" DropShadow="true">
                            </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlSurveyId" runat="server" CssClass="modalBox" Width="250px" Height="100px"
                                Style="display: none;">
                                <asp:Panel ID="pnlIdSurveyName" runat="server" CssClass="caption" Style="margin-bottom: 10px;
                                    cursor: move;">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
                                        <tr style="border: solid 1px balck; background-color: Gray;">
                                            <td>
                                                <strong style="color: White; vertical-align: middle;"><span id="Span2" runat="server">
                                                    Change Survey Id</span></strong>
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="right" valign="top" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                                <img id="imgCloseSurveyId" alt="Close" src="../Images/close.gif" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </asp:Panel>
                                <div style="width: 100%">
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSurveyName" runat="server" Width="190px" Style="margin-left: 30px;">
                                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="padding: 5px;">
                                                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitSurvey" runat="server" Text="Submit" Width="100px" ValidationGroup="SurveyId"
                                                    Style="margin-left: 20px;" OnClick="btnSubmitSurvey_Click" />
                                                <asp:Button ID="btnCancelSurvey" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" Text="Cancel"
                                                    Width="90px" OnClick="btnCancelSurvey_Click" Style="margin-left: 5px;" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: that is not my code, this is auto generated `css` from `AjaxControlToolkit`, so I think I can not modify that...

Comment: you can change it.. make it your own.

Comment: check my updated answer where I use my custom css BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground", CssClass="modalBox"

Comment: I have updated the question. I had already done that and had shared the `CSS` classes here, and the third class is the one that I have seen using Chrome's "Inspect Element"

Answer (score 0):

In your markup:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ... PopupControlID="pnlImageViewer" Y="90" ...
```

you have specified `Y="90"`, this will cause the popup to display 90 pixels off the top. Please try after removing this.

Comment: The problem is not related to popup showing at wrong place. It is because of the background not showing on whole of the page. See my question above. The problem is with background...

Answer (score 0):

apply zindex to the model popup div greater than that of background div

e.g.

```
.modalPopup {
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px #e5e5e5;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #f5f6f5;
    z-index: 90000;
}
```

Comment: As you can see above. The z-index is already higher... The z-index ignores the `position:fixed` divs

Comment: what you are trying to say is confusing to me dear. You should have the background div with position absolute and main popup window as position fixed. This way it should work properly

Comment: see my conversation with nrsharma's answer above http://stackoverflow.com/a/18982084/217757

Answer (score 0):

Try the following(worked for me):

This is the background style for the modal popup

```
.modalBackground 
{
    background-color:#414141;
    filter:alpha(opacity=70);
    opacity:0.7;
    position:absolute;

}
```

Following is the style for the panel which you want to display

```
.Panel_Popup_Style
{
    background-color:White;
}
```